# How to create an application does not depend on jdk

Tags: java, netbeans, jmf

I create project in netBeans use jdk 1.6.
On my computer project is worked, but on other computers do not work. 
on this and I want to create an application that runs on their libraries, how to do it

Comment: See [What's the best way to distribute Java applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105) and [Is there a mechanism to distribute an app with its own JRE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716391)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on other computer there is no JRE then you cannot run your application.

So before that you have to install the JRE on the other's machine.

Or you can provide a installation package that consists of JRE and application.

Comment: search for **Installjammer** and the link is http://www.installjammer.com/ which is used to create installation for Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not tell us what the error was or why it "did not work" on other computers, I take a guess.
And here is the solution: Change the PATH variable so that the java executable will be found.