# Deploying Java application for any target

Tags: java, deployment

I want to be able to deploy my Java application so that it will run on any target (even if the target doesn't have Java installed)

I'm told I must distribute the JRE with my application. Do I literally take a copy of the JRE folder for Windows and one for Linux and have a shell to execute both?

Or are there further steps?

Comment: A related stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716391/is-there-a-mechanism-to-distribute-an-app-with-its-own-jre

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to use an installer.

[BitRock](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com), [Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), etc...

The installer will take care to install the JRE if it doesn't exist on the machine.
Moreover the installers above are multi-platform.

Comment: I dont want to install anything...just run a script

Comment: *"I dont want to install anything"*   That sounds like nonsense here.  To get the app. working, the user machine will need a JRE and the app., both of which need to be installed.  Does the app. have a GUI (it it a desktop app.)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson its a server app. I want them to be able to unzip an archive and run my app with no root privileges

Comment: OK.  I'd say go with the advice in the answer, but I think the fact your clients have no root privileges will put a stop to that.